# XNA: Check if the sound is playing

Tags: xna, c#, sound, sound-effects

Quick question:

I have a `SoundEffect` instance, and I would like to know if it is playing at the moment or not. But there's neither a method, nor a property that would allow to check it...

So, is there a way to know it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer myself :)

Apparently you have to do this:

```
SoundEffectInstance qwe = yourSound.CreateInstance();
qwe.State ...
```

And that state will contain... well, the state of the sound.
Also SoundEffectInstance countains bunch of other useful data.

Comment: Yes, you have to create instances, this way you have more control of your sounds. And also, can you accept your own answer? For marking it as answered.

Comment: @GustavoMaciel done :)